# trying to create a <p> tag using javascript but it tells me "document" doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

```js
let addToDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');

addToDoButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
  toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
})
```

The event listener isn't working when I click the button

Comment: that's true, documents are a browser JS thing... you could get a fake browser for node, or a vdom system, or just build html from strings, depends on what you want to do.

Comment: If you're running this in Node, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: I just used node because I didn't really know how else to see what I was doing wrong. I'm following a tutorial and noticed when I pushed the button, nothing was being added and the <p> tag doesn't exist

Comment: I've updated the linked duplicate. See the answers there for why `getElementById()` might not find your elements

Comment: Thank you, my problem was that my ID element was misspelled in my index.html in comparison to that of my script.js